# unable to deserialize self referential foreign key with custom serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django and django-rest-framework to create APIs

I have a model like this

```py
class Version(models.Model):
    version_tag = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Version"))
    data = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Data"))
    cloned_from = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
    endpoint = models.ForeignKey(
        ManagedEndpoint,
        verbose_name=_("Endpoint"),
        related_name="versions",
        related_query_name="version",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

and a serializer like this

```py
class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.JSONField()
    version_tag = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    cloned_from = ClonedFromSerializer(required=False)
    resource_purpose = serializers.CharField(
        source="endpoint.resource_purpose", required=False
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = models.Version
        fields = [
            "resource_purpose",
            "version_tag",
            "data",
            "cloned_from"
        ]
```

and i have custom serializer `ClonedFromSerializer` like this

```py
class ClonedFromSerializer(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if value.endpoint is None:
            return ""
        return "%s : %s" % (value.endpoint.resource_purpose, value.version_tag)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        resource_purpose, version_tag = data.split(":")
        try:
            endpoint = models.ManagedEndpoint.objects.get(
                resource_purpose=resource_purpose.strip()
            )
            return models.Version.objects.get(
                endpoint=endpoint, version_tag=version_tag.strip()
            )
        except models.ManagedEndpoint.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "invalid clone_from value passed"
            )
```

What I wanted to do is, `cloned_from` should output a string with `resource_purpose` and `version_tag` which is working correctly.

What is not working is that when I make a `post` call i.e. when i want to create a new version with `cloned_from` is passed as a string, it is creating with `clone_from=None`. I don't have a clue why it is still `None` when am returning `Version` object.

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a silly bug. I overridden `create` method in `VersionSerializer` and creating `Version` object like this

```py
return models.Version.objects.create(
                version_tag=_version_tag,
                data=validated_data.pop("data"),
                endpoint=endpoint_obj,
                is_active=True,
                created_by=self.context["request"].user,
            )
```

here, am not passing `cloned_from` ‍♂️

now, i added it and it's working...